# Gradle commandline pass org.gradle.jvmargs

Tags: java, gradle, build, build.gradle, gradlew

How can I pass this params to gradle command

e.g.

```
./gradlew clean build org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

gives error as

```
* What went wrong:
Task 'org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m' not found in root project
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you have written works if you put it in a `gradle.properties` file. If you want to use it on the command line, you first have to add a `-D` (see [command line interface](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#environment_options) in the user guide) but also quote the argument as it contains spaces. E.g.

```
./gradlew clean build "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx8192M -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options\\=\"-Xmx8192M\""
```

works for me

Comment: Bjørn Vester's answer dont' work for me